# Remove filter of a specific component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a group with alot of components.

I apply a filter to this group.

But I would like to remove the filter from one of its components.

If i just set `componentIWantToRemoveFilter.filters = null` it does not work because the filter is applied to the parent component.

There is some way to remove the filter, without apply it to each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, if you apply a filter to `DisplayObjectContainer`, all its children are affected in the sense that they are parts of his appearance (it's different from assigning the same filter to all of its children).

So you could try one of the following:

1. Assign the filter to each component instead of the group (if this gives the result you want and doesn't hurt performances too much) and nullify when you need to
2. Create 2 groups, one with the filter, one without it. If you frequently need to add/remove filters, just use `removeChild()`/`addChild()` to move your components from one group to another